# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined" on $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'))

Tags: jquery, asp.net, unobtrusive-validation

I am dynamically appending a form with a checkbox and a few other input fields. I have added the validate method for all those fields already, which obviously would not work.

I tried to resolve this issue using a below code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response) {
                $(".step-five").find(".payment-section").html(response); //response is from backend and is html file
                $(".step-five").show();

                var $frm = $(".paymentForm");

                // added this to make validator work for the form appended on success
                $frm.data('validator', null);
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($frm);
            }
        }
    })
```

But now, I am getting an error on **$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($frm);**

Error is

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined*

Can anyone please help with this?

TIA

Comment: What do you get in $frm?

Comment: Since this all has to do with Unobtrusive Validation as part of ASP, then please mention that important detail, including more relevant tags.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal - var $frm = $(".paymentForm");

Comment: @Sparky- I don't use ASP. It is pure HTML and jQuery. How is it related to ASP? Do you mean it just work with ASP.NET only?